# C++ emit signal is invoked later in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have qml and c++ side of a project and I am exposing my C++ attributes via `Q_INVOKABLE` and `Q_PROPERTY` macros. My problem is even when I emit a signal in C++, qml side affected after some other code is executed. Can someone propose me a solution?

I have a `status_` member variable and exposing it like this in my header;

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString statusProp MEMBER status_ NOTIFY status_changed)
```

Then, in the .cpp file, I have the function `load_project`;

```
QString controller::load_project(QString proj_name)
{
    status_ = "Loading...";
    emit status_changed();
    clear_layers();
    QString result = db_manager_.load_project(proj_name, engine_list_);
    status_ = "";
    emit status_changed();
    return result;
}
```

Above, status is changed to "Loading...", however emit signal is received after db_manager.load_project() function, hence "Loading..." effect becomes invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the instance of your `controller` class used in the QML part of your application lives in the GUI thread? In this case, what happens is the following:

1. In your code, you set the `status_` and emit the `status_changed` signal. This in fact delivers the signal to QML, but...
2. Control does not return to the event loop, but instead you are calling right into your `db_manager_.load_project()` method which - I guess - is blocking. After this method returns...
3. You set the `status_` back to an empty string and once again emit `status_changed`.
4. As soon as you return from the `controller::load_project` method, control goes back to the Qt event loop and only now the QML part is rendered.

To change this, use threads (via [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)) to run the actual loading in a thread different than the GUI/QML one.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: Your solution works nice and I understand now where I was wrong.